# Why is the total number of electrons in a neutral carbon atom different from the number of dots in a Lewis Dot structure for carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, atoms

Lewis Structure has 4 but the neutral atom has 6. why?

Comment: Because the most involved electrons on bonding are depicted to be the valence electrons.

Answer (score 1):

Only the valence electrons are represented in a Lewis structure. The inner electrons are not important for the bonding, therefore not displayed.